# SQL left join - and after on clause is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario in left join of SQL which is not generating required output which i need. Following is description in tabular form and my tried queries,

**Table A**

```
A_ID        // PK OF TABLE A
IS_ACTIVE   // VALUE=1 OR 0
```

**Table B**

```
B_ID        // PK OF TABLE B
A_ID        // FK OF TABLE A IN TABLE B
```

Sample Records of **Table A**

```
A_ID    IS_ACTIVE
1       1
2       0
3       1
4       0
5       0
```

Sample Records of **Table B**

```
B_ID    A_ID
1       1
2       1
3       4
4       4
5       4
6       4
```

> Select * from A left join B       on A.A_ID=B.A_ID

```
A_ID    IS_ACTIVE   B_ID    A_ID
1       1           1        1
1       1           2        1
2       0           NULL    NULL
3       1           NULL    NULL
4       0           3       4
4       0           4       4
4       0           5       4
4       0           6       4
5       0           NULL    NULL
```

> Select * from A left join B       on A.A_ID=B.A_ID and A.IS_ACTIVE=0

Following output is the **actual output** of above query with no effect to records by adding AND is_active=0 after ON clause.

```
A_ID    IS_ACTIVE   B_ID    A_ID
1       1           1        1
1       1           2        1
2       0           NULL    NULL
3       1           NULL    NULL
4       0           3       4
4       0           4       4
4       0           5       4
4       0           6       4
5       0           NULL    NULL
```

Following output is the **required output** which i need to solve my problem.

```
A_ID    IS_ACTIVE   B_ID    A_ID
1       1           NULL    NULL
1       1           NULL    NULL
2       0           NULL    NULL
3       1           NULL    NULL
4       0           3       4
4       0           4       4
4       0           5       4
4       0           6       4
5       0           NULL    NULL
```

I am facing problem in getting exact records which are required.
I need all records from **Table A** and matching records from **Table B** but 
those records of **Table B** which are equal to is_active=0 of **Table A**.

**Note** : Query should show all records of **Table A**

Please help me how can i get this scenario in Left Join of SQL.

Comment: @JeremyC. did you read the question? it's in the on clause, there is no where clause in his select statement....

Comment: i have not used where clause. i have also used ON clause

Comment: @ZoharPeled my bad, I'm not much awake yet

Comment: Your required output looks weird. e.g. the first two lines `is_active = 1` but `B_ID` still `null`?

Comment: @islamuddin for me your query gives the expected output though

Comment: @StefanSteinegger because there is no b_id for that a_id in table b

Comment: @JeremyC. Sure there is ...

Comment: @StefanSteinegger my bad, misread your comment, again, I have not been awake for long, it is supposed to be null when is_active is 1, it's supposed to show the value for b_id when is_active = 0 (I thought you were talking about the record for a_id 2)

Comment: @JeremyC. I see, I thought it was is_active = 1 ... sorry. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your examples as code. And I get the result you needed. What is the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE #a(a_id int, is_active bit)
CREATE TABLE #b(b_id int, a_id int)

INSERT INTO #a(a_id,is_active)
VALUES(1,1),(2,0),(3,1),(4,0),(5,0)

INSERT INTO #b(b_id,a_id)
VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,4),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4)

SELECT * 
FROM #a as a
LEFT JOIN #b as b
        ON a.a_id = b.a_id
        AND a.is_active = 0

DROP TABLE #a
DROP TABLE #b
```

Comment: Please check again, this is not producing desired result.

Comment: I get the same result as the questioner excepted. what is the difference? Do I oversee something?

Comment: Please see the "required output " mentioned in question. It is not same which your query produced. Somewhere question is confusing.

Comment: As you seen, the answer was marked as answer. So it seems to be the result. :-)

Comment: Thats why I have said the question is confusing. It was not asked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Select * from A left join B on A.A_ID=B.A_ID 
Where A.IS_ACTIVE=0
```